# Есть ли в предложении цитирование и правильно ли оформлено?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитирование

**Твоя фраза: "Я и так это знал" выглядит просто смешно.**

Нужно ли двоеточие? Фраза в кавычках начинается с большой буквы? И на всякий случай спрошу: после кавычек тире не нужно?

Comment: Следовало бы написать, что фраза звучит смешно. А так получается, что у фразы смешной вид (может, рожицы к буквам пририсованы?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Твоя фраза: "Я и так это знал" — выглядит просто смешно.**

Это оформление обычной прямой речи внутри слов автора: тире ставится в случае отсутствия знака препинания на месте разрыва вводящих слов автора (*Твоя фраза выглядит просто смешно.*).
[Знаки препинания при прямой речи. § 136 (б)](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

Мне кажется, что предложение надо "поправить" (так оно лучше воспринимается):
*Твои слова: "Я и так это знал" — выглядят просто смешно.*

2. **Твоя фраза "Я и так это знал" выглядит просто смешно.**

Здесь прямая речь непосредственно включена в авторское предложение в качестве его члена (начинается прописной буквы, двоеточие и тире не ставятся; § 136 (г)).
Я бы выбрала такое оформление.

[Предполагаю, что это предложение — часть диалога, возможно, такого:

— Ничего ценного ты не сообщил. Я и так это знал.
— Придется раскошеливаться! Твоя фраза "Я и так это знал" выглядит просто смешно.

Вот в этом случае идет цитирование (дословное повторение) только что произнесенных кем-то слов.]

Answer (score 0):

Лопатин: § 136. г) если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания ставятся по условиям авторского предложения: Сказав Гричмару фразу «Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть», Крымов поймал на себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова (Бонд.).

Поэтому -  Твоя фраза "Я и так это знал" выглядит просто смешно.
или, например:

Фраза "Мошенник на мошеннике сидит и мошенником погоняет" как нельзя лучше характеризует городских чиновников.

Монолог "Вот то-то, все вы гордецы!", произнесенный Фамусовым, нацелен на защиту традиций высшего общества.

Он вспомнил пословицу "Не плюй в колодец..." и отошел в сторону.

С криком "Спасайте детей!" юноша бросился в горящее здание.

С другой стороны на сайте http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=1275:

Он закончил речь фразой: «..?» (прямая речь)

Девочка пела песенки под возгласы «Браво!». (элемент предложения)

Более подробно:

Вопрос. В каких случаях ставится точка после закрывающей кавычки, перед которой стоит восклицательный/вопросительный знаки/многоточие? И ставятся ли в следующих случаях двоеточия перед открывающими кавычками? Как звучат правила? Ее жизненный девиз – «..!»(.) В их руках плакаты: «..!», «..!»(.) На двери висела записка: "..!"(.) Девочка пела песенки под возгласы(:) "…!"(.) Ему требовалось ответить только на один вопрос (:) «..?»(.) Держали плакаты с надписью (:) «...!»(.) Он закончил речь фразой (:) «…?»(.) Он встал со словами (:) «...!»(.) Как раз, когда сталкиваешься с подобными случаями, долго сомневаешься. Вы не могли бы дать однозначные рекомендации?

Ответ. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это "не хочу" поразило Антона Прокофьевича (в этом примере слова в кавычках пишутся со строчной буквы, так как они выполняют фунцию подлежащего, их легко можно заменить на существительное "слово", "возражение" и др.); Он вспомнил пословицу "Не плюй в колодец..." и отошел в сторону; С криком "Спасайте детей!" юноша бросился в горящее здание. Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение, надпись, выражение и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие, например: На двери висела записка: "Ушла на обед". (См.: Д. Э. Розенталь "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке". М., 2000. C. 169.)
Слова девиза, лозунга, плаката входят обычно в текст как элементы предложения, а не как прямая речь.
Итак, Ваши примеры оформляются так (в скобках после каждого примера обозначено, чем являются слова в кавычках):
Ее жизненный девиз – «..!». (элемент предложения)
В их руках плакаты: «..!», «..!». (элемент предложения)
На двери висела записка: «..!» (прямая речь)
Девочка пела песенки под возгласы: «Замечательно! Хотим еще!» (прямая речь) и Девочка пела песенки под возгласы «Браво!». (элемент предложения)
Ему требовалось ответить только на один вопрос: «..?» (прямая речь)
Держали плакаты с надписью: «..!» (прямая речь)
Он закончил речь фразой: «..?» (прямая речь)
Он встал со словами: «...!» (прямая речь)

На "Грамоте" есть такой ответ на схожий вопрос:

Здравствуйте! Еще раз отправляю вопрос. Ответьте, пожалуйста. Вопрос № 206071: Современное общество живет под девизом(:)«Бог умер! Мы убили его!». Ответ: Двоеточие не требуется. Вопрос № 202528: мероприятие проходило под девизом(:)"..."; Ответ: Корректно: мероприятие проходило под девизом: «...». Как же верно, с двоеточием или без? И еще вопрос. Его кредо: "Никого не обижать" или Его кредо - никого не обижать. Какая пунктуация верна? 
An'ka
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
1.  Ваш вопрос очень сложный, и дать однозначного ответа на него нельзя. С одной стороны, все слова, являющиеся прямой речью и цитатами, выделяются кавычками, перед ними ставится двоеточие. Однако в справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя указано, что подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, заключаются в кавычки, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится. Приводятся такие примеры: *Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься -- ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание*.

2. В то же время ниже в справочнике даётся такая рекомендация. Если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова *предложение, выражение, надпись* и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие, например: *Разберите предложение: «Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром».* 
   На наш взгляд, предложение, в котором содержится слово *девиз*, можно писать как следуя первой рекомендации, так и следуя второй рекомендации. Поэтому окончательное решение о постановке двоеточия принимает автор текста.

Comment: 2. Если в конце цитаты поставлено многоточие, восклицательный или вопросительный знак, то ставится тире, а не запятая:
Когда литсотрудник подписывал ответ на вопрос читателя: “Сохраняются ли витамины в фруктовых соках?” — он, по-видимому, не был озабочен...
И тогда приходится читать: "Зритель встретился с Е. Вициным..." - хотя Вицина зовут Георгий.

Answer (score 0):

*Твоя фраза: "Я и так это знал" -  выглядит просто смешно.*

1.Двоеточие нужно, т.к. есть слово фраза.

2.Тире нужно, потому что по условиям контекста запятая не нужна.

В фразе с цитатой посередине:

a.  перед цитатой двоеточие ставят или не ставят по тем же правилам, что и перед цитатой, которой заканчивается фраза цитирующего (см. п 1а);

b.  после закрывающих цитату кавычек ставят запятую, если цитата входит в состав деепричастного оборота, который ею кончается, или придаточного предложения, также ею завершающегося; например:

Так, девятиклассники, прочитав фразу: "Особенно зорко охраняли англичане морской путь в Индию", спрашивали себя...

или завершает первую часть сложного предложения:
*Несколько редакторов читали следующий текст: "Особенно волнуют молодого читателя книги, в которых он ищет ответы на жизненно важные вопросы", и никто из них не заметил грубой логической погрешности;*
или цитата завершает главное предложение, а далее следует придаточное предложение:

*И тогда приходится читать: "Зритель встретился с Е. Вициным...", хотя Вицина зовут Георгий.*

c.  после закрывающих цитату кавычек ставят тире, если по условиям контекста отделять последующий текст запятой не полагается (в частности, в тексте перед цитатой стоит подлежащее, а в тексте после нее сказуемое или перед цитатой находится один однородный член, а после нее присоединяемый союзом "и" другой):

***Автор после фразы: "Управление производством строится на научной основе" - так цитирует...***

или цитата заканчивается многоточием, восклицательным или вопросительным знаком:
Когда литсотрудник подписывал ответ на вопрос читателя: "Сохраняются ли витамины в фруктовых соках?" - он, видимо, не был озабочен...
или тире необходимо ставить по правилам пунктуации между частью фразы перед цитатой и частью фразы после нее:
Сказать: "чувственное представление и есть существующая вне нас действительность" - значит вернуться к юмизму...

http://www.introweb.ru/inews/content/news478.php